# TypeError: Got a `TypeError` when calling `create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override create() method to handle this

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have this Graph view:

```
class GraphView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = GraphSerializer

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        return {"request": self.request}

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Graph.objects.filter(entity=self.request.source_entity)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):

        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save(entity=self.request.source_entity, creator=self.request.user, context=self.get_serializer_context())

class GraphSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    entity = EntitySerializer(read_only=True)
    creator = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    def validate(self, data):
        
        if data['graph_type'] is None:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Please enter a valid graph type")

        return data
    class Meta:
        model = Graph
```

Iam getting following error while I try POST req:

> TypeError: Got a `TypeError` when calling `Graph.objects.create()`.
> This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class
> that is not a valid argument to `Graph.objects.create()`. You may need
> to make the field read-only, or override the GraphSerializer.create()
> method to handle this correctly.

However, i cant make all fields read-only.
how can i override create ()?

Comment: can you show your `GraphSerializer` class?

Comment: class GraphSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    entity = EntitySerializer(read_only=True)
    creator = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    def validate(self, data):
        if data['graph_type'] is None:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Please enter a valid graph type")
        return data

Comment: Please edit your question and add it there in a readable form, instead of pasting it in the comment. Please also include any nested serializers, the `Graph` model and any relevant models linked by relations that are referenced in those serializers.